# Sort word frequency in Python

Tags: python, sorting, word-frequency

I'm working on building a script that counts word frequency and sorts the results in descending order. I'm having trouble implementing something that sorts the results. Here's my code so far:

```
import re
import string

words = "HELLO how Are yoU i'm doing well thank you."

#remove punctuation
translation = str.maketrans("","", string.punctuation)
stripped = words.translate(translation)
#print(stripped)

##lowercase
words_clean = stripped.lower()
#print(words_clean)

##tokenize
tokens = words_clean.split()
#print(tokens)

##tokenize and word count
def word_count(str):
    counts = dict()

    for word in tokens:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1

    return counts

##sort


print(word_count(tokens))
```

The results that I get are as follows:

```
{'hello': 1, 'how': 1, 'are': 1, 'you': 2, 'im': 1, 'doing': 1, 'well': 1, 'thank': 1}
```

The desired results are:

```
{'you' : 2, 'hello': 1, 'how': 1, 'are': 1, 'im': 1, 'doing': 1, 'well': 1, 'thank': 1}
```

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`. you will get the sorting for free

Comment: you are providing variable str to your function def word_count(str), and using variable tokens inside that function, you should  def word_count(tokens)

Comment: ``dict(sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda i: -i[1]))``